# posting array to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can insert a array into my MySQL database?

I have managed to insert some of this data into the database already.

Below is part of my code:

```
$depart=serialize($_POST['departure']); 
$sql="INSERT INTO bookings VALUES('$depart');
```

I am trying to insert

```
[departure] => Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 05 [2] => 2011 [3] => 17 [4] => 41 )
```

into the database field 'depart'

your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention the data I am trying to insert is from a form, the values in the above array was received from var_dump after form was submitted.

Comment: You might want to learn about [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: You'd better to convert the array to date-time and save it in a datetime field.

Comment: note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Someone did it for you this time, but next time try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'depart' is a datetime field:

```
$timestamp = mktime($depart[3], $depart[4], 0, $depart[2], $depart[1], $depart[0]);

$sql = "insert into bookings(depart) values (from_unixtime($timestamp))";

// Execute the sql as normal
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape your serialized array string.

```
$depart=mysql_real_secape_string(serialize($_POST['departure']));
```